# Moving divs with CSS

Tags: javascript, animation, css

This problem should be pretty straightforward, but I'm new to these methods.

In short, this is what I would like to accomplish: I want to trigger an animation that moves a div a specified number of pixels. That's it. Let's imagine I have buttons on the screen representing each keyboard arrow. Each time you click an arrow the box would move from its current position a specified number of pixels in the appropriate direction.

I originally accomplished this using a transition, but it only works once. I've been searching for the answer to this very BASIC problem for a few hours now and am sincerely frustrated.

Please answer with basic javascript. I'd prefer to not use external libraries for this project.

(edit)
I'm not asking how to accomplish this across all browsers. I'm asking how to accomplish it in any browser.

Comment: While you'd prefer not to use external libraries, I would suggest that jQuery is specifically built for DOM manipulation and would be a great fit. You may have your reasons, just as long as they're not a case of "not invented here".

Comment: I totally agree with Mike Robinson... you should consider library usage for avoiding cross browser problems, simplyfying your code... if you do not want to use it (which is understandable) I suggest you write a basic cross browser working wrapper for adding an event to an element

Comment: If you post the code for your original transition, we might be able to help modify it to be more `live();`

Comment: This is not a "basic" problem. Moving the DIV is not difficult - moving it *smoothly across browsers* is. As Mike Robinson states, there's no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I can't post actual code for legal purposes. I tried to simplify the question enough where code shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I'm not asking how to accomplish this across browsers. I'm asking how to accomplish it in ANY browser.

Comment: That's pretty much the same thing.

Comment: I vote for jquery in this instance as well. I have witnessed it first hand to work better and smoother than browser-native css3 transitions. the animate function can work wonders if you are able to properly clear the animation queues. + the basic function pretty much covers any browser out there.

Answer (score 1):

here is a demo with Javascript/jQuery:

```js
var $ball = $('#ball'); // cache our ball ;)

$('.btn').on('click',function(){
  var direction = $(this).data('move');
  $ball.stop(1); // clear animation queue
  switch (direction){
    case 'up':
      $ball.animate({top:'-=30'});
      break;
    case 'down':
      $ball.animate({top:'+=30'});
      break;
    case 'left':
      $ball.animate({left:'-=30'});
      break;
    case 'right':
      $ball.animate({left:'+=30'});
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
#ball{
  position:absolute;
  left:60px;
  top:60px;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn" data-move="up">U</button>
<button class="btn" data-move="down">D</button>
<button class="btn" data-move="left">L</button>
<button class="btn" data-move="right">R</button>

<div id="ball"></div>
```

### *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/jenoci/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)*

Comment: He stated multiple times he didn't want to use jQuery - why would you give a jQuery answer?

Comment: @user1090190 Thanks for reminding me to buy a pair of glasses, but I hope you know that the Q does not fit the ... Just read the FAQ. I just want to show the simplicity of actually using a library. *"...I'd prefer to not use external libraries for this project..."* does not mean *"I don't want"* or *"I cannot"*.

Comment: it's ok. Thanks for the jquery answer. More than likely I'm going to have to fall back on it in the end.

Comment: @Heineman99 You're welcome. Thanks for leaving a comment. Make sure to read this for the future. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your ElementToMove is positioned absolutely in CSS, you could theoretically add something like the following to your click handler:

```
var elementToMove = document.getElementById( 'ElementToMove' );
while ( elementToMove.left < elementToMove.left + 10 )
{
  window.setTimeout(
    function ( )
     {
       elementToMove.style.left = (elementToMove.style.left + 1) + "px";
     },
     100
   );
 }
```

The number `10` in Line 2 would be the predetermined amount to move when the button is clicked.

Essentially what this does is moves the object 1 pixel every tenth of a second (the `100` in line 9) until it moves as far as you wanted it to.  You could accomplish the same with `setInterval( )` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery to get the capture the click. I used plain old javascript to move the div.  I believe you will want to get comfortable with jquery if you want to do much DOM manip in javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>move it</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box" style="position: absolute; left: 2px; top: 5px; width: 100px; height: 100px;
        background-color: Red;">
    </div>
    <div id="buttons" style="position: absolute; left: 2px; top: 100px;">
        <button id="down"  >
            down
        </button>
        <button id="right"  >
            right
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function moveDown() {
        var xx = document.getElementById('box');
        var top = parseInt(xx.style.top);
        xx.style.top = top + 12 + "px";
        console.log(xx.style.top);
    }

    function moveRight() {
        var xx = document.getElementById('box');
        var left = parseInt(xx.style.left);
        xx.style.left = left + 12 + "px";
        console.log(xx.style.top);
    }

    $(function () {
        $("#down").click(moveDown);
        $("#right").click(moveRight);
    });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I originally did something like this, but need the animation of the object. Thanks though.